# Does Rails 3 have an equivalent to merb's run_later function built-in?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to do background processing using closures.  I don't care if the app crashes in the middle of this, as it will be idempotent and have many opportunities to be run, so it doesn't need a heavy-weight solution like Starling.  In merb, I was able to do this with:

```
data_to_process = get_that_data
run_later do
  # process data in the data_to_process variable
end
# do work that needs to be responsive and
# doesn't depend on the processing of data_to_process
```

Is there an equivalent built in to Rails 3, or do I need to use one of the myriad plugins that were written to do something like that for Rails 2.2 and later?  If I have to use a plugin for this kind of thing, which one is best for this use?  It should ideally require no configuration and should take closures, as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running things at a later time, [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) is the community standard. I would recommend learning how to use this and apply it to your situation.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that delayed_job is what I should probably be using.  It is quite heavy compared to run_later, so I may just use a thread pool for now.

Answer (score 2):

run_later port to Rails 3:
https://github.com/jkraemer/run_later